# Ansible and scp_extra_args in config file

Tags: ansible, arguments, config

So I did an upgrade to OpenSSH 9.4p1 and that broke (kinda) my ansible.

Made it work but it's not using neither scp neither sftp, it's falling back to tunneled ssh.

So I tried with

scp_extra_args = "-O" in the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg file.
Doesn't work, that extra argument is not passed to scp.

BUT running the playbook with --scp-extra-args='-O" works ok.
Setting scp_extra_args: "-O" in the groupvars works also.

Just that in the config file is not picked up.

Any hint on how to make it work from the config file??

AFAIK it is supposed to work.

Virtual env with python 3.6.8, ansible 2.9.6 on CentOS 7.9 and Oracle linux 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"How to make it (scp-extra-args) work from the config file?"***

A: It is not possible to configure *scp-extra-args* in the Ansible configuration file. There is no such [option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings). You can test it

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump | grep -i scp
```

You can configure it, as you've already found out, either in the *ansible-playbook*

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook --help | grep -i scp
                        [--scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS]
  --scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to scp only (e.g. -l)
                        specify common arguments to pass to sftp/scp/ssh (e.g.
```

, or in the variable [ansible_scp_extra_args](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-scp_extra_args)